# MS Excel 2016, Power View, Image URL unable to increase size

Tags: excel, data-visualization, powerview

GitHub Repository with [photos.xlsx](https://github.com/RanaDataViz/photos/blob/master/photos.xlsx) file and Photographs ([link](https://github.com/RanaDataViz/photos))

Software: MS Excel 2016 with Power View enabled

---

I created Power View report in [photos.xlsx](https://github.com/RanaDataViz/photos/blob/master/photos.xlsx)  that displays photograph and numbers next to it.

How do I increase size of photograph?

Increasing Font size doesn't increase photo size

I simply cannot select the corner and drag.

And I cannot find FORMAT option to increase size.

HELP!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think images added to the Power View are only static so they can,t be changed in size once in the Power View.

Check this link out: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/81202bdb-4892-45b8-a1ae-67f09058a53f/can-i-expand-image-size-in-power-views-table-?forum=powerview